How to create two users of different permissions in Django？
How to set up two different types of users in Django: superusers, who have access to all system features, and maintenance users, who can perform system maintenance. These are users created in the backend management system, not logged-in users in the front-end interface. They are created automatically when the system is initialized. Thanks in advance.
As a beginner, there aren't too many ideas. I'm just going to create an initial user. I'd love for ideas and related reference codes. Thank you here.
The documentation is very detailed, but I just Django framework, I don't understand, sorry, can you provide a specific approach?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

That is already the case, in fact a User has an .is_superuser field and an .is_staff.

The documentation is very detailed, but I just Django framework, I don't understand, sorry, can you provide a specific approach?

Django's builtin User model [Django-doc] has already two fields .is_staff [Django-doc] and .is_superuser [Django-doc] are booleans to "promote" a user to a staff account and a superuser account.
If you have a view that should only be accessible to staff users, you can use the @staff_member_required [Django-doc] decorator:
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required


@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
    # …
    pass
then the my_view will bounce if the user is not a User with is_staff is True.

What I mean by this is that administrators can only have access to some of them, not that some views can only be viewed by administrators, that is, they control the permissions of the logged-in user, not the permissions of the views
